# How can I create a button that increments a counter when clicked?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am trying to make a button that increments a counter's value by 1 when clicked. My code, however, doesn't seem to work.

```js
var count = 1;
var button = document.querySelector("#increment");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var increment = document.getElementById("#count");
  increment.value = count;
  count++;
});
```

```html
<h4>Current count: <span id="count">0</span></h4>
<div class="container">
  <button id="decrement">Decrement</button>
  <button id="increment">Increment</button>
</div>
```

Comment: When you use `.getElementById()` you are selecting elements by id, so you don't need the `#`. You *do* need it, though in `querySelector`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need `#` in `getElementById` and use `innerHTML` to set value.
Don't use `querySelector` when you can get by id.

Like this:

```js
let count = 0;
const button = document.getElementById("increment");
const button2 = document.getElementById("decrement");
const textHolder = document.getElementById("count");
textHolder.innerHTML = count;

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  textHolder.innerHTML = ++count;
});

button2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  textHolder.innerHTML = --count;
});
```

```html
<h4>Current count: <span id="count">0</span></h4>
<div class="container">
  <button id="decrement">Decrement</button>
  <button id="increment">Increment</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code have some issues

1. Use `#` in query selector, remove it, it use in jquery
2. Wrong attribule `value` change to `innerText`
3. Change `querySelector` to `getElementById` to get id

```js
var count = 1;
var button = document.getElementById("increment");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var increment = document.getElementById("count");
  increment.innerText = count;
  count++;
});
```

```html
<h4>Current count: <span id="count">0</span></h4>
<div class="container">
  <button id="decrement">Decrement</button>
  <button id="increment">Increment</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with this short JS inserted in the HTML button elements:

```html
<h4>Current count: <span id="count">0</span></h4>
<div class="container">
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('count').innerText--">Decrement</button>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('count').innerText++">Increment</button>
</div>
```

If you want to use a function you can try something like this:

```js
function changeValue(diff) {
  var count = document.getElementById('count');
  count.innerText = +count.innerText + diff;
}
```

```html
<h4>Current count: <span id="count">0</span></h4>
<div class="container">
  <button onclick="changeValue(-1)">Decrement</button>
  <button onclick="changeValue(1)">Increment</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.document.getElementById()` doesn't need CSS selector indicator, you can just pass the id value directly here is how to do it, note that I'm using  `+` operator to make sure that the `textContent` parsed into integer, and to increment the value you can just add `++` after that to `count` tag that we have reference to, here is a working snippet:

```js
var count = 1;
var IncrementBtn = document.querySelector("#increment");
var decrementBtn = document.querySelector("#decrement");

IncrementBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var increment = document.getElementById("count");
  +increment.textContent++;
});

decrementBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var decrement = document.getElementById("count");
  +decrement.textContent--;
});
```

```html
<h4>Current count: <span id="count">0</span></h4>
<div class="container">
  <button id="decrement">Decrement</button>
  <button id="increment">Increment</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input id="result"  type="text" class="form-control">

    <button onclick="Increment()" type="submit">+</button>
    <button onclick="Decrement()" type="submit">-</button>
    <button onclick="AllClear()">
```

AC

function
function Increment() {
result.value  ++

```
    }
    function Decrement() {
        if(result.value>0){
            result.value  --
        }
        
        
    }


    function AllClear() {
        result.value = ""

    }
```